# What is the best orientation for growing flowers?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I went on Thonky's Animal Crossing New Leaf Wiki and read the hybrid flowers guide. It said change the orientation for increased likelihoods. I'm having trouble understanding what this means. The guide states that

> The orientation of your flowers might have an effect. In previous Animal Crossing games, having the flowers touch diagonally was better, but in other games, having them in straight rows was better..

Could someone explain in more detail what this means?

Answer (score 1):

When you have two flowers they can be placed like so:

```
@@
```

Or

```
@
@
```

Or

```
@•
•@
```

Thonky is saying that vertical, or horizontal, or diagonal planting might be  better.

Comment: This clarifies what is meant by the linked quote, but do you actually know what different orientations do?

Comment: @SadlyNot That's not what was asked though, the question is just about what it means. The original source is quite clear already that no one seems to know yet if and which orientation is best in New Leaf

Answer (score 0):

As DanBeale explained, it's about the placement of flowers next to each other.

My girlfriend, who has played New Leaf a lot, says she feels as if she has been seeing much better results since she adopted a style in which she basically "fences" buildings etc, like this:

```
******
*xxxx*
*xxxx*
******
```

Where x is the building and * the flowers. Which means she's NOT using diagonal placement like in the old games, but rather horizontal/vertical placement only.

Don't forget though that the biggest improvement to the whole process is using the **golden watering can**. [image]